# Execute immediate with IN clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I have statement like,

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO TABLE (SELECT * FROM SOMETABLE)';
```

and it works fine.

When I try to use WHERE with IN clause it is throwing error

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO TABLE (SELECT * FROM SOMETABLE WHERE COLUMN_VALUE IN ('||'EMP'||','||'PEN'||','||'CWK'||') )';
```

What am I doing wrong here. Is this feature supported in oracle?

Comment: Why are you using `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` for a simple `INSERT`? It should work just fine if you just use `INSERT INTO TABLE (SELECT...`

Answer (score 1):

You are not escaping the string values.  The immediate solution for you is to add the single quotes for the values in the `IN` list.  To do so, you need to duplicate the single quote (it escapes itself), so the query looks like:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO TABLE SELECT * FROM SOMETABLE WHERE COLUMN_VALUE IN (''' || 'EMP' || ''',''' || 'PEN'|| ''',''' || 'CWK'|| ''') ';
```

However, you might want to look at alternative ways of passing values into a query; munging strings can be dangerous, particularly if they are user input.

In addition, the parentheses are not needed for the `SELECT`.  And, you should be listing all the columns for the `INSERT`.

Comment: Yeah, someting like _EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE employees_temp SET commission_pct = :x'  USING 123;_